# How to add new column into table based on header title instead of position?

Tags: vba

I want to add a new column into a table after a certain header title in which the position will vary from time to time.

I can use this code to add a column at position 4 but the position depends on the header title which may changes.

Any clue on how to go on about this?

`Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns.Add Position:=4`

E.g.: Header title is in position 5, the code will add a new column in position 6.
E.g.: Header title is now in position 7, the code will add a new column in position 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `HeaderRowRange` property of the `ListObject` to solve this:

```vb
Dim HeaderTitle as String, i as Integer, MyTable as ListObject

HeaderTitle = "YourTitleGoesHere" 'change to match your title
Set MyTable = Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table1")
With MyTable.HeaderRowRange
    For i = 1 to .Count
        If .Cells(i).Value = HeaderTitle Then
            MyTable.ListColumns.Add Position:= i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Using `.Rows(i).Value` works too, but I think I'll use `.Cells(i).Value` as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just change "YourHeader" to your header name

```
Sub AddColAfterHeader()
    [Table1[YourHeader]].Next.EntireColumn.Insert
End Sub
```

..or this if the surroundings matter

```
Sub AddColAfterHeader2()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns.Add _
    ([Table1[YourHeader]].Next.Column - [Table1].Column + 1)
End Sub
```